# Why do we change the order of summation?

Tags: soft-question

Alexander the Great is staring at the Gordian Knot, bewildered. Absentmindedly he fingers the hilt of his trusty sword.  On the sword is inscribed the words: "Change the order of summation".

Mathematics is full of multiple-sum computations in which the crucial step is to change the order of summation.  Unlike Alexander, though, I often see no conceputally clear reason why it ought to make the answer fall out.  It is so unreasonably effective that I am tempted to do it without even thinking.

Is there some unifying reason why one should try changing the order of summation?

Or, to put it another way, maybe this is confirmation bias talking.  Are there interesting computations where it's *possible* to change the order of summation, but the correct approach is *not* to change it?

Comment: You could ask the same about «adding and substracting»... For changing the order of summation/integration/differentiation/etc, one could arguer that nature is devious and never presents youwith things in their most useful ways.

Comment: More generally, it is often very enlightening to compute the same quantity in two different ways. For example, I'm sure you know lots of theorems that are proven by counting the elements of a set in two different ways. However, I really don't think this is a good MO question, so I'm voting to close. Even your specific question has no good answer, because of your implicit assumption that there is a "correct" way to prove a result. Generally, different proofs have different merits.

Comment: On a related note, even for computers it is "easier" or rather faster to compute nested sums in certain order. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope_model

Comment: Maybe it is selection bias? You only remember the times when you HAVE to change the order of summation. Besides, you are of course more likely to have success if you actually manipulate your expression. 
I think this question sounds like "Why is it more likely to compute something by manipulating it?"

Comment: Because the loose change in your pocket gets mixed all the time...?

Comment: On a side note, people do often slowly put a hand on their swords while still wondering whether to do it or not, starting with Achilles in the remarkable Iliad I, 193-194.

Answer (score 1):

I see the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope_model) is not very enlightening. Since this got too big for a comment I'm posting it as an "answer".

Disclaimer: I'm just an interested bystander so take the following with a grain of salt.

The point is that nested sums (say over indices $i,j,k$) have bounds which cut out (usually) a polyhedron in $n$-dimensional (here $n=3$) space and you are summing over the lattice points inside that polyhedron. Now certain boundary tests for $i,j,k$ are easier computed than others, certain orders in which you traverse the lattice is faster due to cache/memory locality issues. Also, you may discover that some parts of your computation doesn't really depend on each other and you can run them on separate CPUs. Which circles back to mathematics...

Changing the order of summation (or more generally traversing your lattice in other way) can decompose parts of your expression which enables you to simplify it by "summing per partes".